# Xamarin.Forms can you define the data in a data context in XAML

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app I have a custom control that displays a list of data. The data is defined in an IEnumerable ViewModel. Normally the view model is defined dynamically in C# but I was wondering if it was possible to define it in XAML? For example in my XAML I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="WrhseCtrls.Views.CollapsibleGridPage"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WrhseCtrls;assembly=WrhseCtrls">
<ContentPage.Content>     
    <local:Views.CollapsibleGridView Title="No View Model">
        <local:Views.CollapsibleGridView.BindingContext>
            <local:ViewModels.ListViewItem/>
        </local:Views.CollapsibleGridView.BindingContext>

        <local:ViewModels.ListViewRow Caption="Row" Text="Text"  Hidden="False" Height="30"></local:ViewModels.ListViewRow>

    </local:Views.CollapsibleGridView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The view model 'ListViewItem' is an IEnumerable of'ListViewRow.' Is it possible to populate this view model in XAML, like I have tried to do in the 'ListViewRow' line? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do exactly as you did, instantianting and adding itens to a custom IEnumerable class. But if I'm not wrong, you can use it this way:

```
<ContentPage.Content>     
    <local:Views.CollapsibleGridView Title="No View Model">
        <local:Views.CollapsibleGridView.BindingContext>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:ViewModels.ListViewRow}">
                <local:ViewModels.ListViewRow Caption="Row 1" Text="Text 1"  Hidden="False" Height="30"></local:ViewModels.ListViewRow>
                <local:ViewModels.ListViewRow Caption="Row 2" Text="Text 2"  Hidden="False" Height="30"></local:ViewModels.ListViewRow>
                <local:ViewModels.ListViewRow Caption="Row 3" Text="Text 3"  Hidden="False" Height="30"></local:ViewModels.ListViewRow>
            </x:Array>
        </local:Views.CollapsibleGridView.BindingContext>
    </local:Views.CollapsibleGridView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```